# Is there a way to decrypt S/MIME public key data?

Tags: java, encryption, public-key, smime

I would like to get the email address and expire date to a S/MIME certificate based on it's public key. Is this aproach even possible? Or am I totally wrong? Can I decrypt the public key to get these kind of data via java?

I searched in google, read the wiki pages and read about an oracle s/mime project. But it doesn't seam like its possible. Are those data only availabe in the csr??

Thanks in advance

Comment: This shows, that it must be possible: https://askubuntu.com/questions/977246/viewer-for-x-509-certificate

Comment: I guess I will have to take a deeper look into bouncycastle.

Answer (score 3):

I'm amazed this isn't a dupe, but I couldn't find a good one.

Although Bouncy is fine and has many features if you want to use it, core Java can handle X.509 certificates since forever. For a cert in a file (or anything that can be accessed as a Stream) in *either* PEM or DER format (although the javadoc isn't clear on that) all you need is [CertificateFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/security/cert/CertificateFactory.html):

```
CertificateFactory fact = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

// from a real file
InputStream is = new FileInputStream ("filename");
Certificate cert = fact.generateCertificate(is);
is.close(); // or use try-resources to do automatically

// from an alternate/custom filesystem, such as a ZIP
Path p = Paths.get("somespecification"); // or any other creation of a Path
InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(p); // add open options if needed
// same as before

// from the classpath (usually a JAR)
InputStream is = ClassLoader /*or any Class<?> object*/ .getResourceAsStream("name");
// same as before

// from a byte[] in memory
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream (bytearray);
// same as before, except don't really need to close

// you get the idea
```

Although JCA APIs like this one are defined to allow a lot of extension,  reading an X.509 cert will actually give you not just `Certificate` but subclass [`X509Certificate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/security/cert/X509Certificate.html) from which `.getNotAfter()` gives the expiration date-time directly. The email address if present (which isn't required by X.509 certs in general, but should always be the case in a cert used for S/MIME) will usually be an attribute in the subject name, which actually has internal structure that Java doesn't let you get at directly so you need to:

```
String x500name = ((X509Certificate)cert).getSubjectX500Principal()) .toString();
// simple case: no multivalue RDN, no reserved chars ,+="<>\;# or extra spaces 
for( String attr : x500name.split(", ") )
  if( attr.startsWith("EMAILADDRESS=") ) 
    ... use attr.substring(13) ...
// other cases require slightly more complicated parsing
```

Note there is no encryption at all in X.509, and thus no actual decryption, although many people use 'decrypt' to describe anything unfamiliar not an actual cipher.

Comment: Thank you very much for this alternative solution! I apreciate this. Can you also please tell me wether S/MIME certificates are always in X509? What's the difference between PEM and DER? I am new to this

Comment: Effectively yes: S/MIME (an IETF standard) is based on CMS (an IETF standard evolved from PKCS7, an RSA-Labs standard) which for certificates uses PKIX (another IETF standard which is a variant of X.509, a CCITT-now-ITU-T standard). There are tiny technical differences between X.509 and PKIX, but the same code handles both. CCITT/ITU-T standards and some others (including CMS/PKCS7/SMIME) encode their data using [ASN.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One) and usually [BER or DER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.690); certificates in particular use DER. ...

Comment: ... DER is binary data, not valid text. Back when [PEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy-Enhanced_Mail) was developed in the 1990s email systems mostly couldn't handle binary data, so it established a convention of base64-encoding the binary data with line breaks and added header and trailer lines. PEM itself is no longer used, but PEM format remains common as a convenient way to handle binary data. Email systems today _can_ handle binary (using the same MIME which underlies S/MIME) but other things like cut&paste cannot.

Comment: See also https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/183072/pem-cer-crt-p12-what-is-it-all-about and https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/73156/whats-the-difference-between-x-509-and-pkcs7-certificate

Comment: I have a task basically to check if the certificate received from LDAP server is correct (Enc or Auth). How can I check this when I know the certificate is X.509 type ? Is there any way I can retrieve this information from the certificate ?

Comment: @ashwinlagji: If you mean S/MIME, which was the topic of this Q, it uses the same cert for signing (which is data authentication) and encryption; there is no entity authentication. There is an attribute in SignerInfo (outside the cert) that can specify user-agent capabilities, but it's not clear to me how much this is used. If you mean other applications it can vary a lot (they may not even _have_ features that could be called Enc and Auth) and anyway doesn't belong in this Q. In _some_ cases the KeyUsage and/or ExtendedKeyUsage extensions may help, and are in the javadoc I linked already.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I just have to verify if I can encrypt the mail using the received certificate( in Java). I was wondering which fields and how they give this information in the certificate. I'll have look at ***KeyUsage*** and/or ***ExtendedKeyUsage*** information. It looks promising. If you have any more data to add please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
    File file = new File(fileName);
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
    PEMParser pemParser = new PEMParser(fileReader);
    X509CertificateHolder caCertificate = (X509CertificateHolder) pemParser.readObject();
```